# Google OAuth2 Invalid token format error on redirecting to PWA

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I have an error when login with Google OAuth. No problem on desktop website or mobile browser usage with google login. But the user wants to login on mobile browser and PWA of the web site installed on device then mobile browser redirecting to PWA after click google login. PWA gets token from GET but it is giving "Invalid token format" error.

"Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format in /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php:449"

Returning URL from google is:

https://example.com/google/?code=4/tokenxxx&scope=email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid&authuser=1&hd=xx.com&prompt=none

```
$accessToken = $this->gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( trim( $_GET['code'] ) );
$this->gClient->setAccessToken( $accessToken ); // error line
```

There is no error on desktop usage or without mobile browser redirecting to PWA.

I need some ideas.

Edit:
$this->gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( trim( $_GET['code'] ) ) function is returning "invalid_grant" error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and noticed that in the case of PWA authentication on Android there are two identical requests being made to the OAuth2 callback handler (the URL that the user is sent to by Google after authenticating), with time difference of a second or two. Internally that handler asks Google servers for an OAuth token in exchange for the authorization code. Apparently, the code can only be used once, so the second time Google servers respond with a 400. What seemed to fix it for my App Engine app is to add caching to the OAuth2 callback handler (set 'Cache-Control' to e.g. 'public, max-age=600'), so that the second request gets a cached response.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it temporarily on PWA with redirect to login url again.

```
if ( isset( $accessToken['error'] ) ) {
    die( Url::redirect( HTTPSURL . "social/google/" ) );
}
```